# Parameters not being used explicitly

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, java-8

Excuse my lack of knowledge. I am very new to spring and hibernate. I was handed over source code that was developed by someone else and I am trying to understand the logic of it. The following method should use the parameters organisationId and date to produce a customised result but it doesn't seem to be using the parameters at all. Is it possible that the method is using the parameters implicitly? Am I missing something?

```
public JSONProcessImprovementOptions getProcessImprovementOptions(Integer organisationId) {

    Iterable<WasteTypeEntity> wasteTypeEntityList = wasteTypeRepo.findAll();
    Iterable<WorkPackageEntity> workPackageEntityList = workPackageRepo.findAll();

    List<JSONWasteTypes> wasteTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<JSONWorkPackages> workPackages = new ArrayList<>();

    wasteTypeEntityList.forEach(entity -> {
        JSONWasteTypes wasteType = new JSONWasteTypes();
        wasteType.setName(entity.getName());
        wasteType.setWasteTypeId(entity.getId());

        wasteTypes.add(wasteType);
    });

    workPackageEntityList.forEach(entity -> {
        JSONWorkPackages workPackage = new JSONWorkPackages();
        workPackage.setName(entity.getName());
        workPackage.setWorkPackageId(entity.getId());

        workPackages.add(workPackage);
    });

    JSONProcessImprovementOptions options = new JSONProcessImprovementOptions();
    options.setProcessImprovementEnabled(true);
    options.setWasteTypes(wasteTypes);
    options.setWorkPackages(workPackages);

    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it dosent seem to use inputs...

It seems the code get every instance of WasteTypeEntity and WorkPackageEntity

Then generates new lists out of the items inserting name and id from fetched entities.

Finally it generates JSONProcessImprovementOptions object, and set both list into the option object.

```
   options.setProcessImprovementEnabled(true);
    options.setWasteTypes(wasteTypes);
    options.setWorkPackages(workPackages);
```